# javascript for imacros concerning time

Tags: javascript, extract, imacros

I am working with audio files that i need sorted out for transcription. I already have this code to extract the time duration.

TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:duration-holder EXTRACT=TXT

what i want to do next is to sort them when the extracted value is 
greater than > 5:00 it should then TAG POS=1 ATTR=...
and if the value is
less than 5:00 then it should TAG POS=2 ATTR=....

i hope you can help me figure this out. i am not very familiar with javascript and read in most solutions here that you need a javascript for this if/else sort of automation.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:duration-holder EXTRACT=TXT
SET pos EVAL("(parseInt('{{!EXTRACT}}') >= 5) ? 1 : 2;")
' TAG POS={{pos}} ATTR=...
```

---

Dealing with the seconds:

```
SET pos EVAL("var p = 2; var v = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\d\d:(\d\d)/)[1]; if (v < 26) p = 1; else if (v > 75) p = 3; p;")
```

Comment: you're a genius man. thanks a lot, this works. i have one more tweak that i can't figure out though. instead of 5 minutes, i want to compare the extracted values in seconds. extracted value is in time mm:ss format and i am hoping to: 
tag pos=1 if time is less than or equal to 25 seconds;
tag pos=2 if time is more than of equal to 26, but less than or equal to 75 seconds; 
tag pos=3 if time is more than or equal to 76
***the parseInt worked like a charm, thanks again and hope to hear back again from you***

Comment: See the update and don't forget to let me know whether it proves to be useful.

Comment: this is exactly what i need. the macro does exactly what it is supposed to do. thank you very much Shugar for the help.

Comment: why is it that when i run .match(/\d\d:(\d\d/)[1] it is not showing the minutes. for example, v = 2:43 the .match function only registers 43 as the array instead of 243?

Comment: Because of the index equal to **1**. You should read something about regular expressions in JavaScript.

Comment: i used the SLICE() instead of .match. a little bit longer but it does the trick. :D